# How to determine if three ints are all equal

Tags: c#

Hi say I have three ints: value1, value2 and value3.

How do I best determine if they are all the same?

I tried:

```
return value1 == value2 == value3
```

But this said:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'.

So I guess it compares the first two which returns a boolean which it tries to compare to the third.

I could go:

```
return value1 == value2 && value2 == value3;
```

But this seems to be getting untidy.

Anybody have a good suggestion?

Comment: Most languages don't support your first syntax (the only language I know that *does* support that syntax is Python).

Comment: @NullUserException you sir have a proper name. Well done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second seems just fine to me.

As the list gets longer, that could get unwieldy.  In which case I'd write an extension method along the lines of `AllSame`.

```
bool AllSame(this IEnumerable<int> list)
{
    bool first = true;
    int comparand = 0;
    foreach (int i in list) {
       if (first) comparand = i;
       else if (i != comparand) return false;
       first = false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

or use the `params` keyword:

```
bool AllSame(params int[] list)
{
    return (list as IEnumerable<int>).AllSame();
}
```

Then you can just write:

```
if (AllSame(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5)) ...
```

Comment: I can believe this got selected as the right answer... as there is already an **All** extension method.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar, `All()` does something different. And if you meant something like `list.All(x => x == list.First())`, then that wouldn't work for collections that can be iterated only once.

Comment: +1 for exit on first fail, really all this needs to be perfect is a goto.

Comment: @RitchMelton: Not sure why you'd want a goto.  I thought about pulling the first iteration out separately, to avoid testing `first` on every loop, but it'd be much uglier, especially if you tried to maintain exception safety.

Comment: @Ben - For sarcastic awesomeness.

Comment: @RitchMelton What are you trying to say? Are you implying we should follow the antiquated, cumbersome and senseless practice of having only one exit point per method?

Comment: @NullUserException - No, I thought it was a nice touch that he exited early. The goto was a comment on the future-proofing the check of 3 elements for equality (params and static are my least favorite keywords).

Answer (score 6):

That seems fine to me. The only comment I have is that you should introduce an 'explaining variable' for the equation. Besides explaining the calculation, the return now provides a nice place for a breakpoint or a tracepoint when inspecting the result.

```cs
bool allThreeAreEqual = value1 == value2 && value2 == value3;
return allThreeAreEqual;
```

Answer (score 6):

I modified my original answer to include a method that is more general purpose and that does not rely on LINQ or extension methods.  I think it's safe to assume this method would be more performant based on the fact that it doesn't have to enumerate the entire list to determine uniqueness when there are values that are different early on in the list.

```
class Program 
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        int value1 = 1, value2 = 2, value3 = 1; 
        Console.WriteLine(AllAreEqual<int>(value1, value2, value3));

        Console.Write("V2: 1 value ");
        Console.WriteLine(AllAreEqual_V2<int>(1));

        Console.Write("V2: no value ");
        Console.WriteLine(AllAreEqual_V2<int>());

        Console.Write("V2: 3 values, same ");
        Console.WriteLine(AllAreEqual_V2<int>(1, 1, 1));

        Console.Write("V2: 3 values, different ");
        Console.WriteLine(AllAreEqual_V2<int>(1, 1, 2));

        Console.Write("V2: 2 values, same ");
        Console.WriteLine(AllAreEqual_V2<int>(1, 1));

        Console.Write("V2: 2 values, different ");
        Console.WriteLine(AllAreEqual_V2<int>(1, 2));

        Console.ReadKey(); 
    } 

    static bool AllAreEqual<T>(params T[] args) 
    { 
        return args.Distinct().ToArray().Length == 1; 
    }

    static bool AllAreEqual_V2<T>(params T[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 0 || args.Length == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (args.Length == 2)
        {
            return args[0].Equals(args[1]);
        }

        T first = args[0];

        for (int index = 1; index < args.Length; index++)
        {
            if (!first.Equals(args[index]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1; `ToArray().Length == 1` can be compacted into `Count() == 1`.

Comment: O_o. Wow. That's general purpose.

Comment: Thanks Merlyn, Appreciate the refinement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for elegance (Considering your already have a solution that has nothing wrong with it ) , you could go with good'ol LINQ. This can handle three or more.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> mylist = new List<int>();
            mylist.Add(1);
            mylist.Add(1);
            mylist.Add(1);
            mylist.Add(1);

            bool allElementsAreEqual = mylist.All( x => ( x == mylist.First() ));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I doubt it will return any quicker... There is nothing in **All** that makes it necessary to examine all elements...

Comment: for some reason I had two thinko's in a row. Sry.

Comment: If one of them doesn't match... All returns false, If two of them doesn't match it returns false... So as soon as All finds one of them doesn't satisfy the predicate it has no need to evaluate the predicate on the remaining elements. Are you saying it is not the case ? The MSDN documentation mentions **The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined.**

Comment: How about _not_ assuming what you don't know? Apparently someone else had a good reason to downvote. But you're in good company. I think someone just disliked LINQ for this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this also

```
bool AllSame(int a, int b, int c, int comparand) {
    return board[a] == comparand && board[b] == comparand && board[c] == comparand;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int nOneInput = 5;
int nTwoInput = 5;
int nThreeInput = 5;
if ((nOneInput + nTwoInput + nThreeInput ) / 3 ==  nOneInput ) 
{
    // all 3 sides are equal when...
    // the sum of all 3 divided by 3 equals one of the values 
}
```

Comment: This can be wrong if you have something like { 5, 4, 6 }. The average would still be 5 but you would be unable to determine if all 3 are equal.

Answer (score -1):

Using LINQ it would be best to us `Any()`. Why `Any()` instead of `All()` is because `All()` will test the predicate on all the items of the collection while `Any()` will exit as soon as and item match the predicate.

Here i use a reverse check. I am looking for any item that will be different than the item "a". So as soon it find one different we know they are not all equals so it exit and return true. So it will only test item "b", "c" and "d".

```
// all values to compare
var a = 4;
var b = 4;
var c = 4;
var d = 8;
var e = 6;
var f = 4;

// return if any of the following is different and negate to get a true
var areSame = (!new[] { b, c, d, e, f}.Any(i => i != a));
```

If you override equals you can create generic extensions from this that is reusable and can work for multiple type as long as they implement `IEqualityComparer<T>`

Comment: `All()` will exit as soon as one item does not satisfy the predicate.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I would do

```
if((value1 == value2) && (value1 == value3) && (value2 == value3))
{
    //Whatever you want here
}
```

Comment: (value1 == value2) && (value2 == value3)  is enough.

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer works fine, but I needed to support different types too,
so this is the generic version

```cs
      public static bool AllSame<T>(params T[] items)
         {
            var first = true;
            T comparand = default;
            foreach (var i in items)
            {
               if (first) comparand = i;
               else if (!i.Equals(comparand)) return false;
               first = false;
            }
            return true;
         }
```

usage:

```cs
if (AllSame(true, false, true)) // false
if (AllSame(5, 5, 5)) // true
if (AllSame(record1 , record2, record3))
```